# AIR render performance on top of object

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, air

I am working on Adobe AIR project targeting on mobile devices.

I have a toggle sliding menu that has a hundred items and scrolling feature.

When menu opens on empty screen it's working realy smooth.  But the menu behind has an object or vector shapes  then fps is slowing down and scroll animation lagging.

There is a sample draw here:

[image]

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Have you tried using the `.cacheAsBitmap` property of your vectors? and are you publishing with GPU acceleration?

Answer (score -2):

Don't use any vector on mobile devices. At the minimum, don't display vector and instead draw them into a bitmapdata and display that instead. vector graphics require heavy CPU work and on mobile devices you will reach the CPU limit very fast. So all your displayed graphics have to be at least bitmapdata. 
If it's not enough you could also mix with a Stage3D framework like Starling to take care of your background graphics and save even more CPU power.

Comment: Thank you. I know that and a lot of things converted bitmap data but i have some dynamic objects and i cant use bitmap. Starling is great. maybe i will work with it for next project but now thats not answer to my problem.

Comment: It is the answer to your problem. The fact you don't don't like it doesn't make it less of an answer since you won't find any other solution to your problem: vector on mobile devices slow down fps period.